# Command is giving me "bash: ./fwupd: cannot execute binary file"

Tags: 11.04, live-cd, ssd

Whenever I issue the command

```
./fwupd /dev/sda
```

I get the following:

```
bash: ./fwupd: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm trying to update my SSD's firmware using Ubuntu 11.04 LiveCD.

How do I successfully issue the command?

Comment: Likely you are in the wrong directory. Try running `sudo updatedb && locate fwupd` to find where that app is

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are sourcing the file, instead of running it.

Try executing it using the full path, something like

```
sudo /home/user/fwupd /dev/sda
```

Comment: The full path is unnecessary. However, you're true on the sourcing part for which +1

Comment: @Lekensteyn: What do you suggest then? The error message suggests sourcing, but the command itself looks OK, not something like `. ./fwud`. Confusing.

Comment: You're right, it shows something else like `bash: .: ./fwupd: cannot execute binary file`. It looks like an arch issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried some things and it looks like you're trying to execute the 64-bit `fwupd` binary on a 32-bit Live CD.

Grab the .zip file (which is in fact a tarball, shame on them) from http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/ and extract it using `tar`. E.g. if the file is named `fwupd_v2.12.05.zip`, run:

```
tar xf fwupd_v2.12.05.zip
```

Then jump into the directory containing the 32-bit `fwupd` binary and run it with superuser privileges:

```
cd fwupd_v2.12.05/linux32
sudo ./fwupd /dev/sda
```

Note that if the reverse happens (e.g. you're running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit machine without compatibility libraries), the error is different:

```
bash: ./fwupd: No such file or directory
```

This can be solved by installing `ia32-libs` (for Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and before) or `libc6:i386` (for Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric and up).

Finally, if the file was not executable, the error would be:

```
bash: ./fwupd: Permission denied
```

This would be solved by making it executable:

```
chmod +x fwupd
```

Comment: That must be it ;)

Comment: Interesting. I've done some more research (execute_cmd.c) and it seems bash tries to execve() the command, but execve returns with ENOEXEC because of the arch error. Unfortunately bash does not return this error directly, but tries to give a smarter error message by testing if the file is a bash script or a binary file. In this case it would be better if we got the original *Exec format error* message from execve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the permissions on the file? It should be `chmod 0755 fwupd`

Answer (score 0):

I had a file named 'env' and was getting the same error:

```
. env
bash: .: /usr/bin/env: cannot execute binary file
```

It turned out that env was some kind of reserved name, which was causing problems.  Changing the name to something more obscure solved it.