# fwupd to update OCZ RevoDrive firmware gets a 'Permission denied' error

Tags: live-usb, ssd, firmware

Try as I might I just don't get it working http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_RevoDrive_and_RevoDrive_X2/.

There's another thread here with an similar issue here: [Command is giving me "bash: ./fwupd: cannot execute binary file"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63443/command-is-giving-me-bash-fwupd-cannot-execute-binary-file)

I'm running command `./fwupd /dev/sdb` which keeps returning me `bash: ./fwupd: Permission denied` error.

I have tried running both bit versions available of fwupd with both of the latest 32- and 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10, running the OS from an USB stick, but to no avail (could this be the problem?). In the other thread it was suggested that `chmod +x fwupd` (or `chmod 0755 fwupd`) should resolve this issue, but at least for me it has been for naught. It was also suggested to install certain libraries, but those were already included in the Ubuntu build and I didn't have any luck after updating with apt-get. I also tried giving fwupd more privileges, r, x and w but same charade, run it in different ways from different places (where I'd have the fwupd present, ofc) among other things.

What I also tried is giving the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS a shot but it didn't even launch on either of my computers, though that's not the issue here.

If anyone has any ideas on what the problem is and how I could get this working, it would be most appreciated!

Comment: I can't believe I found the answer on my own just after posting this after messing around with it for hours. The problem was that I was trying to run it from the fwupd that was located on my HDD, instead of... well I'm not exactly sure where I ran it from, but what's important is that it worked! If this question can be deleted I have no qualms about it, sorry! sudo updatedb && locate fwupd is what helped me to solve this, I just didn't think it wouldn't allow me to run it from the other locations that I had it in.

Comment: This is great! Please consider using the "Your Answer" box below to post your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

*(Comment by OP answered own question)*

The problem was that I was trying to run it from the fwupd that was located on my HDD, instead of... well I'm not exactly sure where I ran it from, but what's important is that it worked! If this question can be deleted I have no qualms about it, sorry! sudo updatedb && locate fwupd is what helped me to solve this,

I just didn't think it wouldn't allow me to run it from the other locations that I had it in. – Late Nov 30 '11 at 22:45

Answer (score 0):

Either the file was not set executable (chmod +x), or you had it on a mount which was marked noexec, which will prevent executables from being run from it (/tmp is often marked noexec as a line of defence).